mysql - how to get date of first user ticket
I have a tickets table with this info:
ticket_id    |    user_id   |   used_at
----------------------------------------
xxx          |      xxx     |   datetime
xxx          |      xxx     |   datetime
xxx          |      xxx     |   datetime

I want to get a list of all users who has ONLY ONE TICKET and USED_AT date of it.
My current select works to get user and their first ticket date.
SELECT
  washtickets.id,
  washtickets.user_id,
  washtickets.used_at
FROM
  washtickets,
  (SELECT user_id, min(used_at) AS used_at FROM washtickets GROUP BY user_id) max_user
WHERE
  washtickets.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND washtickets.user_id = max_user.user_id
  AND washtickets.used_at = max_user.used_at
ORDER BY
  used_at ASC;

But I don't know to add COUNT(*) to filter only users who has ONLY ONE used ticket.
Any help?

First JOINS are SQL Standard for over 20 years, so please use them
Count is an aggregation function, so you need a GROUP BY
All columns that are not in the GROUP BY must have a aggregation function, as you only want people with one ticket, so the id should be have one numbers so the aggregation function doesn't matter.
SELECT
  MIN(w.id),
  w.user_id,
  w.used_at
  
FROM
  washtickets w JOIN
  (SELECT user_id, min(used_at) AS used_at FROM washtickets GROUP BY user_id) max_user
ON
  w.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND w.user_id = max_user.user_id
  AND w.used_at = max_user.used_at
GROUP BY w.user_id, w.used_at
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY
  used_at ASC;


Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but I do not see the need for the subquery.
It is not completely clear what you want as you start off by saying -

all users who has ONLY ONE TICKET and USED_AT date of it.

but later say -

only users who has ONLY ONE used ticket.

Either way I cannot see the need (or benefit) in the subquery.
This query returns all users with only one ticket which is not deleted and has a used_at value:
SELECT
  MIN(ticket_id) AS ticket_id,
  user_id,
  MIN(used_at) AS used_at
FROM washtickets
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
AND used_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

Here's a db<>fiddle.
